# Filter Context data by user input

Tags: entity-framework, filter, dbcontext

I am using MVC with Entity framework.

I have a Client requirement that client want to set default period for all the context table. When he set some date range into the user setting page it saves the detail to the sql table. When the app runs application all the data from table will come for that particular period.
I want to apply this filter in my context file.

Here is my context file and suppose i got the date here.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contact_phone> Contact_phones{ get; set; }
}
```

How i achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: I think [query interceptors](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/database-command-interception.aspx) can help you to achive what you want

Comment: @AdilMammadov Can you help me with a clear example.

Comment: I am sorry, I haven't used it myself, I just know about it.